# how to remove some elements from the response in golang

Tags: json, go, go-gorm, go-fiber

I am studying gofiber, I am using GORM and github.com/morkid/paginate,
I want to remove the child element from the response.
this is the response

```
{
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "CreatedAt": "2023-01-22T02:33:12.604+08:00",
                "UpdatedAt": "2023-01-22T02:33:12.604+08:00",
                "DeletedAt": null,
                "email": "ilham@mail.com",
                "username": "",
                "names": "",
                "posts": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "created_at": "2023-01-22T01:59:42.611+08:00",
                        "updated_at": "2023-01-22T01:59:42.611+08:00",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "title": "using loop",
                        "body": "tes body postman 2",
                        "UserID": 1,
                        // i want remove this 
                        "User": {
                            "ID": 0,
                            "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                            "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                            "DeletedAt": null,
                            "email": "",
                            "username": "",
                            "names": "",
                            "posts": null
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "page": 0,
        "size": 10,
        "max_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 1,
        "total": 1,
        "last": false,
        "first": true,
        "visible": 1
    }
}
```

i want the response like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "CreatedAt": "2023-01-22T02:33:12.604+08:00",
                "UpdatedAt": "2023-01-22T02:33:12.604+08:00",
                "DeletedAt": null,
                "email": "ilham@mail.com",
                "username": "",
                "names": "",
                "posts": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "created_at": "2023-01-22T01:59:42.611+08:00",
                        "updated_at": "2023-01-22T01:59:42.611+08:00",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "title": "using loop",
                        "body": "tes body postman 2",
                        "UserID": 1, 
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "page": 0,
        "size": 10,
        "max_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 1,
        "total": 1,
        "last": false,
        "first": true,
        "visible": 1
    }
}
```

this is my user model

```
package models

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email    string `gorm:"unique" json:"email"`
    Username string `gorm:"unique" json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"-"`
    Names    string `json:"names"`
    Post     []Post `gorm:"Foreignkey:UserID;association_foreignkey:ID;" json:"posts"`
}
```

this is my post model

```
package models

import (
    "time"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Post struct {
    ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    Title     string         `json:"title"`
    Body      string         `json:"body"`
    UserID    uint           `gorm:"column:user_id"`
    User      User
}
```

and this is the handler to get all user data

```
func GetAllUser(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var users []models.User
    model := initializers.DB.Preload("Post").Find(&users)

    return c.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(fiber.Map{
        "data": initializers.PG.With(model).Request(c.Request()).Response(&[]models.User{}),
    })
}
```

i am using gofiber and gorm to create this code

Answer (score 0):

try to add `json:"-"` to User field

```
type Post struct {
    ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    Title     string         `json:"title"`
    Body      string         `json:"body"`
    UserID    uint           `gorm:"column:user_id"`
    User      User           `json:"-"`
}
```